# Regex replace special character

Tags: c#, regex

I need help in my regex.

I need to remove the special character found in the start of text

for example I have a text like this

```
.just a $#text this should not be incl#uded
```

The output should be like this

```
just a text this should not be incl#uded
```

[I've been testing my regex here but i can't make it work](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5b%5c!-%5c%2f%5c%3b-%5c%40%5d%2b%29%5b%5cw%5cd%5d%2b&i=.just+a+%24%23+text+this+should+not+be+incl%23uded%0d%0a)

```regex
([\!-\/\;-\@]+)[\w\d]+
```

How do I limit the regex to check only the text that starts in special characters?

Thank you

Comment: Try this: `^([\!-\/\;-\@]+)` is this what you're after?

Comment: Hi @Isaac it should also include the $#text

Comment: Do you want to remove all the special characters or some of them only? you question details are confusing.

Comment: will it always be the first character only that you want to remove ?

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49814944/3832970), looks like it covers all the cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\B[!-/;-@]+\s*\b`:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(s, @"\B[!-/;-@]+\s*\b", "");
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5CB%5B!-%2F%3B-%40%5D%2B%5Cs*%5Cb&i=.just%20a%20%24%23%20text%20this%20should%20not%20be%20incl%23uded%0D%0A&r=)

**Details**

- `\B` - the position other than a word boundary (there must be start of string or a non-word char immediately to the left of the current position)
- `[!-/;-@]+` - 1 or more ASCII punctuation
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `\b` - a word boundary, there must  be a letter/digit/underscore immediately to the right of the current location.

If you plan to remove all punctuation and symbols, use

```
var result = Regex.Replace(s, @"\B[\p{P}\p{S}]+\s*\b", "");
```

See [another regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cB%5b%5cp%7bP%7d%5cp%7bS%7d%5d%2b%5cs*%5cb&i=.just+a+%24%23+text+this+should+not+be+incl%23uded%0d%0a&r=).

Note that `\p{P}` matches any punctuation symbols and `\p{S}` matches any symbols.

Comment: Thank you for the good solution with a detailed explanation how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Use lookahead:

`(^[.$#]+|(?<= )[.$#]+)`

The `^[.$#]+` is used to match the special characters at the start of a line.

The `(?<= )[.$#]+)` is used to matching the special characters at the start of a word which is in the sentence.

Add your special characters in the character group `[]` as you need.

Answer (score 1):

Following are two possible options from your question details. Hope it will help you.

```
string input = ".just a $#text this should not be incl#uded";

//REMOVING ALL THE SPECIAL CHARACTERS FROM THE WHOLE STRING    
string output1 = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^0-9a-zA-Z\ ]+", "");

// REMOVE LEADING SPECIAL CHARACTERS FROM EACH WORD IN THE STRING. WILL KEEP OTHER SPECIAL CHARACTERS     
var split = input.Split();
string output2 = string.Join(" ",  split.Select(s=> Regex.Replace(s, @"^[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "")).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

Negative lookahead is fine here :

```
(?![\.\$#].*)[\S]+
```

https://regex101.com/r/i0aacp/11/

`[\S]`    match any character

`(?![\.\$#].*)`  negative lookahead means those characters `[\S]+` should not start with any of `\.\$#`